# Using common DOM/ Window object across multiple tabs of same domain

Tags: javascript, html, dom, window, client

Is there any way to share a common DOM/ Window object across multiple tabs of same domain. 
The use case is a form will be shown in all the tabs (inline) of the webapp and any input/change in the form should be reflected in the form in all other tabs, but without using server.
I had gone through Web Storage elements such as BroadCast Channel and IndexedDB, but DOM/Window objects cannot be saved using it. So the way is to publish only the data of the form using the Web storage elements and listen and handle in all other tabs.
But, want to know is there really any other way to use a common DOM in multiple tabs or share the DOM to other tabs.

Comment: Simple answer is no, not in the way I think that you are describing. There is the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) but as far as a "common" D(ocument) O(bject) M(odel) in multiple tabs? That really doesn't make much sense when you think about it. Each is tab is it's own "document" and therefor has it's own DOM. Your house and my house are houses but they are not the same house.

Comment: Thanks @gforce301 but consider the below case.
Suppose Tab A and Tab B are two tabs of same domain 'abc.com' and now Tab A loads iframe X with src as 'xyz.com'. Now, there are 3 window/Document object and Tab A has basic access(show/hide/positioning) of the iframe X . Now, imagine if tab A could share this iframe content to Tab B through any means similar to data sharing or if the iframe src can be set to point any local html so that both tabs load the iframe pointing same Document Object, then the mentioned case could be easily achieved.Yes,I could not find anything but Won't it make sense?

Comment: Even in the case of an iframe. The DOM for each iframe is it's own instance, created at the time the frame is loaded. So you wold not see changes from Tab A on Tab B because they are different DOM instances. I understand what  you are saying and what you want to happen. It seems that you are confusing the actual document with the DOM. I think of it this way: The actual document is what the initial request ... requested. The DOM instance is created from it. It is a construct of the browser not of the actual requested document. HTML does not specify a DOM.